# Passprops equivalent for Navigator?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, navigator

I am trying to convert from NavigatorIOS to Navigator and can't seem to figure out how to make passprops work.  I'm trying to pass two variables, LRA and email to the next scene, but I keep getting undefined.  I'm very new to this so I'm sorry if this is an easy question. Here is my code so far, feel free to give me any other tips you see wrong with it!

DataEntry.js

```
  class DataEntry extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state = {
          emailString: 'default@gmail.com',
          isLoading: false,
          message: '',
        mailerror: false,
        lraerror: false
        };
    }

  onEmailTextChanged(event) {
    this.setState({ emailString: event.nativeEvent.text });
    if (!validateEmail(this.state.emailString)){
      this.emailError = "Please enter a valid email"
      this.setState({error: true})
    }
    else{
      this.emailError = ""
      this.setState({error: false})
    }
    }

  onLRATextChanged(event) {
    this.setState({ LRAString: event.nativeEvent.text });
    if (!isValidID(this.state.LRAString)){
      this.LRAError = "Valid LRA ID is 4-10 alphanumeric characters"
      this.setState({error: true})
    }
    else{
      this.LRAError = ""
      this.setState({error: false})
    }
  }

  gotoNext() {  
    var emailtext = this.state.emailString
    var LRAtext = this.state.LRAString
    console.log(emailtext)
    this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'PasswordView',
        name: 'Generated Password',
        email: emailtext,
        LRA: LRAtext
    });
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var email = this.state.emailString
    var LRA = this.state.LRAString
    return (    
      <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.description}>
                Please enter the email and LRA
            </Text>

            <View style={styles.flowRight}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.searchInput}
                value={this.state.emailString}
                onChange={this.onEmailTextChanged.bind(this)}
                placeholder='Enter Email'/>
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.error}>
              {this.emailError}
            </Text>

            <View style={styles.flowRight}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.searchInput}
                value={this.state.LRAString}
                onChange={this.onLRATextChanged.bind(this)}
                placeholder='Enter LRA ID'/>
            </View>

            <Text style={styles.error}>
              {this.LRAError}
            </Text>


            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                underlayColor='#99d9f4'
                onPress={this.gotoNext.bind(this)}>
               <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Retrieve Password</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text style={styles.description}>{this.state.message}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
render() {
        return (
          <Navigator
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          navigator={this.props.navigator}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar style={{backgroundColor: '#48BBEC', alignItems: 'center'}}
                routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
          } />
        );
      }  
}

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return null;
  },
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return null;
  },
  Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', margin: 10, fontSize: 16}}>
          Data Entry
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
};


module.exports = DataEntry;
```

Comment: The Navigator code seems unfinished to be honest. I ended up going with https://github.com/exponentjs/ex-navigator which seems to make more sense. They did a full write-up here: https://medium.com/the-exponent-log/routing-and-navigation-in-react-native-6b27bee39603

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to separate your Navigator into its own component, then you can assign the properties you need on the navigator as needed (in this case, the ...route.passProps spread operator being the property setting up passProps for use by the navigator).

I've set up the project with your code at https://rnplay.org/apps/V_EhdA.

Below is the code I used to get it working.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

function isValidID(string) {
    return true
}

var Two = React.createClass({
    render(){
    return(
        <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Hello From second component</Text>
          <Text>id: {this.props.id}</Text>
          <Text>name: {this.props.name}</Text>
        </View>
    )
  } 
})

var Main = React.createClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
          emailString: 'default@gmail.com',
          isLoading: false,
          message: '',
          mailerror: false,
          lraerror: false
      }
    }, 

  onEmailTextChanged(event) {
    this.setState({ emailString: event.nativeEvent.text });
    if (!validateEmail(this.state.emailString)){
      this.emailError = "Please enter a valid email"
      this.setState({error: true})
    }
    else{
        this.emailError = ""
        this.setState({error: false})
      }
    },

  onLRATextChanged(event) {
    this.setState({ LRAString: event.nativeEvent.text });
    if (!isValidID(this.state.LRAString)){
      this.LRAError = "Valid LRA ID is 4-10 alphanumeric characters"
      this.setState({error: true})
    }
    else{
      this.LRAError = ""
      this.setState({error: false})
    }
  },

  gotoNext() {  
    var emailtext = this.state.emailString
    var LRAtext = this.state.LRAString
    this.props.navigator.push({
        passProps: {
            id: 'PasswordView',
            name: 'Generated Password',
            email: this.state.emailstring,
            LRA: LRAtext,
        },
        component: Two
    });
  },

    render() {
      var email = this.state.emailString
      var LRA = this.state.LRAString
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.description}>
                Please enter the email and LRA
            </Text>

            <View >
              <TextInput
                style={{height:40}}
                value={this.state.emailString}
                onChange={this.onEmailTextChanged.bind(this)}
                placeholder='Enter Email'/>
            </View>

            <Text >
              {this.emailError}
            </Text>

            <View >
              <TextInput
                style={{height:40}}
                value={this.state.LRAString}
                onChange={this.onLRATextChanged.bind(this)}
                placeholder='Enter LRA ID'/>
            </View>

            <Text>
              {this.LRAError}
            </Text>

            <TouchableHighlight style={{padding:30}}
                underlayColor='#99d9f4'
                onPress={ () => this.gotoNext() }>
               <Text>Retrieve Password</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

        <Text >{this.state.message}</Text>
      </View>
    );
}
})

class DataEntry extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    } 
        render() {
        return (
          <Navigator
          configureScene={() => {
                      return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
                  }}
          initialRoute={{name: 'ComponentName', component: Main, index: 0}}
          renderScene={(route, navigator) =>    {
            if (route.component) {
                          return React.createElement(route.component, { ...this.props, ...route.passProps, navigator, route } );
                      }
        }}

          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar 
            style={{backgroundColor: '#48BBEC', alignItems: 'center'}}
                routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
          } />
        );
      }  
}

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if(index > 0) {
      return (
      <TouchableHighlight  style={{marginTop: 10}} onPress={() => {
            if (index > 0) {
              navigator.pop();
            } 
        }}>
       <Text>Back</Text>
     </TouchableHighlight>
 )} else {
 return null}
 },
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return null;
  },
  Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', margin: 10, fontSize: 16}}>
          Data Entry
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {flex:1},
    description: {flex:1}
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DataEntry', () => DataEntry);
```

Comment: this worked, thanks! But one quick thing now is that my navigationbar doesnt work any more.  How would I create a back button?

Comment: It looks like you're returning null for both buttons. I've gone into the above code and edited it to add a back button. Let me know if this is what you had in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I realized what i was forgetting as soon as you posted the code, I had originally put a back button in my next scene but obviously that does not work with the navigator now its own component. Thank you for all the help, really great and thorough answer!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that experienced with React Native yet, so this might not be the best practice but I ended up with

```
renderScene: function(route, navigator) {
  return (
    <route.component route={route} navigator={navigator} />
  );
}
```

Where route.component can be any of your Screens (main Views).

And then setting state on the Navigator itself, since it has its own state and it is now passed as a prop to every View:

`this.props.navigator.setState({isLoading: true});`

To some extent it is an High Order Component.