# Navigator with args

Tags: react-native

I created an Android app with Navigator.

On my first page, I want to push differents informations to the next page if I push with a button or with an other.

I created gotoNext function as below. But, I don't understand how I can replace my typedmg: 'test' by an argument which represent the button Pole or Aerial.

Thanks for your help.

```
class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          navigator={this.props.navigator}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper= NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
      } />
);
}
renderScene(route, navigator) {
return (

....


      <View style={{flex: 4, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <TouchableHighlight name='Pole' onPress={this.gotoNext}>
          <Image source={require('./img/radio_damage_pole.png')} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight name='Aerial' onPress={this.gotoNext}>
          <Image source={require('./img/radio_damage_aerial.png')} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

...

);
}
gotoNext() {
 this.props.navigator.push({
  id: 'page_user_infos',
  name: 'page_user_infos',
  typedmg: 'test',
});
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up your Navigator to pass properties by assigning the passProps spread operator to the Navigator.  The best way to do that is to separate your navigator into it's own component, then assign properties to it.

I've taken your project and set up a similar functioning one [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/UeyIBQ). There was another similar thread you may be able to reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763709/passprops-equivalent-for-navigator/33767091#33767091) as well. Below is the code I used to get it working, I hope this helps!

https://rnplay.org/apps/UeyIBQ

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity
} = React;


class Two extends React.Component {
    render(){
    return(
        <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Hello From second component</Text>
          <Text>id: {this.props.id}</Text>
          <Text>name: {this.props.name}</Text>
            <Text>name: {this.props.typedmg}</Text>
        </View>
    )
  } 
}

class Main extends React.Component {       

  gotoNext(myVar) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      component: Two,
      passProps: {
          id: 'page_user_infos',
          name: 'page_user_infos',
          typedmg: myVar,
        }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <View style={{flex: 4, flexDirection: 'column', marginTop:40}}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={{height:40, borderWidth:1, marginBottom:10}} name='Pole' onPress={ () => this.gotoNext('Pole') }>
        <Text>Pole</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={{height:40, borderWidth:1, marginBottom:10}} name='Aerial' onPress={ () => this.gotoNext('Aerial') }>
        <Text>Aerial</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>)
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <Navigator
          initialRoute={{name: 'Main', component: Main, index: 0}}
          renderScene={(route, navigator) =>    {
            if (route.component) {
                          return React.createElement(route.component, { ...this.props, ...route.passProps, navigator, route } );
                      }
                }}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
      } />
);
}
}

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if(index > 0) {
      return (
      <TouchableHighlight  style={{marginTop: 10}} onPress={() => {
            if (index > 0) {
              navigator.pop();
            } 
        }}>
       <Text>Back</Text>
     </TouchableHighlight>
 )} else {
 return null}
 },
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return null;
  },
  Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', margin: 10, fontSize: 16}}>
          Data Entry
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
};


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 28,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    fontSize: 19,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I need a Button Next in my Navigator. It's the reason why I write my Navigator bar in all my page, to change the push().

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: My problem is the choice of the property when I click on a button. When I click on Aerial, I want that typedmg = 'aerial' and when I click on 'pole', I want that typedmg = 'pole'. Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Sure, check out the example and above code now, I've passed in a variable to be rendered on the onPress function to pass the correct variable. I've also updated the example project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's perfect.