# Howto pass data to a other component with react native Navigator

Tags: react-native

i'm using a Navigator component and want to pass data from a component to a other.
here is some code.

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var routeId = route.id;
    if (routeId === 'SplashPage') {
        return (
            <SplashPage
        navigator={navigator} />
    );
    }
    if (routeId === 'Login') {
        return (
            <Login
        navigator={navigator} />
    );
    }
    if (routeId === 'Home') {
        return (
            <Home
        navigator={navigator} />
    );
    }
    ....
```

I want to pass data from login to home when i click on a button for example

```
this.props.navigator.replace({
        id: 'Home',
        passProps: {
            currentUser: this.user,
        }
    })
```

i would like to get the currentUser in the Home Component. I've tried some code that i found but nothing seem to work.

This is whant i want to do :

```
class Home extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.currentUser = ????????
}
```

If anyone can help me with this i would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up your renderScene method like this:

```
renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
  return React.createElement(route.component, { ...this.props, ...route.passProps, navigator, route } );
}}
```

And use it like this:

```
this.props.navigator.replace({
    component: Home,
    passProps: {
        currentUser: this.user,
    }
})
```

And in Home, you can access currentUser like this:

```
<Text>{ this.props.currentUser }</Text>
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830493/react-native-navigator/33831700#33831700) thread for a more detailed example, but that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help.