# Navigator this.props.navigator.push

Tags: react-native

I can't seem to make my routing work in my react native app.

I have the following setup in a index.android.js:

```js
class MainClass extends Component {

render() {
    return NavigationService.navigationSetup();
}
```

and in NavigationService

```js
var React = require('react-native');
var Login = require('./login/Login');
var ProjectList = require('./project/list/ProjectList');
var ProjectView = require('./project/view/ProjectView');

var {
    Navigator
} = React;

var renderScene = function (route, navigator) {

var routeId = route.id;

if (routeId === 'Login') {
    return (<Login {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator} />);
}

if (routeId === 'ProjectList') {
    return (<ProjectList {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator} />);
}

if (routeId === 'ProjectView') {
    return (<ProjectView {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator} projectId={route.passProps.projectId} />);
}
};

var navigationSetup = function () {
return (
    <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id: 'Login', component:Login}}
        renderScene={renderScene.bind(this)}
    />
);
};

module.exports = {
    navigationSetup: navigationSetup
};
```

and in ProjectListView:

```js
   this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'ProjectView',
        passProps: {
            projectId: projectId
        }
    });
```

The routing from Login to ProjectList works. But when I try to via a list click navigate to ProjectView I get:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigator.push).
```

I've looked at guides and tried different things but it seems that navigator isn't there ...

Would be great if someone could help me out.

Also another question: routing/navigation does not work from me when I enable debugging in Chrome (using Genymotion), is that normal?! 
Tried different projects ...

Cheers
Niclas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you need to define passProps in your renderScene method. You can do this in either of two ways. One, by passing the passProps into your component using a spread operator:

```
if (routeId === 'Login') {
       return (<Login {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator}/>);  
}
```

Or, you can create a component manually and pass it using React.createElement (this may scale a little better):

```
renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
  return React.createElement(route.component, { ...this.props, ...route.passProps, navigator, route } );
}}
```

There was a discussion about the above method today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390638/pass-value-from-view-to-view-react-native/35392022#35392022).

I've set up a working sample project [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/gJWkQQ) with some of your code, and pasted everything below for you to check out.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
     var routeId = route.id;

     if (routeId === 'Home') {
         return (<Home navigator={navigator}/>);
     }

    if (routeId === 'Login') {
           return (<Login {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator}/>);  
    }

     if (routeId === 'About') {
         return (<About {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator}/>);
     }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Navigator
            initialRoute={{ id:'Home', name: 'Home', component: Home }}
        renderScene={ (route, navigator) => this._renderScene(route, navigator) }
        />
    );
  }
});

var About = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
        <View style={ styles.container }>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.props.goBack() }>
            <Text>Go Back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text>Hello from About</Text>
        <Text>{ this.props.message }</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
})

var Login = React.createClass({
    render() {
    return (
        <View style={ styles.container }>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.props.goBack() }>
            <Text>Go Back</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text>Hello from Login</Text>
        <Text>{ this.props.message }</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
})

var Home = React.createClass({

  navigate(id, message) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        id: id,
      passProps: {
        message: message,
        goBack: this.goBack,
      }
    })
  },

    goBack() {
        this.props.navigator.pop()
    },

    render() {

    return (
        <View style={ styles.container }>
        <Text>Hello from Home</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.navigate('About', 'This is the about page!') } style={ styles.button }>
            <Text>GO TO ABOUT</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.navigate('Login', 'This is the login page!') } style={ styles.button }>
            <Text>GO TO Login</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
})

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:60
  },
  button: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ededed',
    marginTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Can't get it to work .. I must be doing something really dumb :(
added the {...route.passProps} to the "routing".
I can see in my NavigatorService that navigator and route are ok BUT it seems I can't pass the navigator to ProjektList.
The flow is Login => ProjectList ...

Comment: Is Login the `initialRoute`?

Comment: Yepp.

        <Navigator
            initialRoute={{id: 'Login'}}
            renderScene={renderScene.bind(this)}
        />

Comment: Maybe try this
`<Navigator {...route.passProps} initialRoute={{id: 'Login'}} renderScene={renderScene.bind(this)} />`

Comment: Can't seem to do that since in my setup route is not available.
Updated NavigatorService.js

Comment: Is navigationSetup being set up outside of the actual component? RenderScene needs to be in the same class or component definition as the Navigator.

Comment: Check out this gist to see what I'm talking about https://gist.github.com/dabit3/f865a48ce6df4195e977

Comment: Cheers for taking your time to help. 
Added that code into index.android.js
Sadly it seems I'm that I'm still not getting it to work in the ProjectList component, I cant access navigatior..

Comment: Can you post your entire code maybe on a github gist?

Comment: Ahhhhh damn .. just realised that ProjectListView is a component I created which I don't pass in navigator to ... 
So ProjectListView is a ListComponent which is used in ProjectList ..

So sorry to have wasted your time, thank you for trying to help!